# In Python 2.7, create individual headers in csv from items in a list

Tags: python, list, csv, list-comprehension

I have a list of values that I would like to add (automatically) as individual headers in my csv file.

I cant seem to get the logic correct - this is what i have thus far:

```
unique_fields = ['buffcount', 'size', 'ctype', 'atype', 'idiameter', 'row', 'pstatus', 'perminal']

with open(r"C:\Temp\test2\new.csv", 'wb') as outfile:
   f = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

   f.writerow(["FDomain", "CValue", "Descr", unique_fields])
```

This is what I want the headers to look like:

FDomain | CValue | Descr | buffcount | size | ctype | atype | idiameter | row | pstatus | perminal

What's the best way to add these list items as individual headers?

I've tried list comprehension ( fl for fl in unique_fields ) at the f.writerow function but I get a `<generator object <genexpr>` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
f.writerow(["FDomain", "CValue", "Descr"] + unique_fields)
```